# Visualize gRPC and Protocol Buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, visualizer

We are close to 100 `.proto` files, where every may define around 10 IDL structures (like `service` or `message`).

Is there a way to visualize of of them, including references (from one file to other). For example similar to UML class diagram.

Possibly there are configurable visualizer for Java/C++.

Quote from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

> Protocol buffers are now Google's lingua franca for data – at time of writing, there are 48,162 different message types defined in the Google code tree across 12,183 .proto files.

I wonder how they handle this.

Comment: Google doesn't have this problem.  It's pretty rare in practice to need to visualize protos.  Do you have a specific problem you want to solve?  How would visualizing help that problem?

Answer (score 25):

https://github.com/seamia/protodot

- Super easy to use and pretty powerful tool
- Generates .dot (and .svg/.png if `graphviz` is installed) files from .proto
- Discovers all the dependencies and doesn't require all of them to be present
- Filters by specified resources (messages, rpcs, services, enums)
- Can generate import dependency graph

[image]

Comment: This should be chosen as the answer! so much better than all the tools listed earlier. Thanks @grayhemp

Answer (score 17):

I have similar problem: I'm trying to read huge amount of protobufs and understand relation between them. It would be very useful to build a visual representation of them to see what's available and how they're connected to each other.

I've found several projects, maybe they would help someone:

- [protoc-gen-uml](https://github.com/tssp/protoc-gen-uml)
- [protobuf2uml](https://github.com/vak/protobuf2uml)
- [schema-uml](https://github.com/malisas/schema-uml)
- [protoc-gen-doc](https://github.com/pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc)

Though, for me they didn't worked well for different reasons, but you can try them.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17805368)

Comment: Why do you think it's not answering the question? Topic starter asked for a way to visualize gRPC/Protobufs -- I provided a link of available projects which supposed to do what he asks.

Comment: Perhaps add context around the links so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.